# Return JSON from WCF service

Tags: json, wcf

I want remove first and Last place og double Quote in JSON,

```
public interface ITFSService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "TFS_GetProject", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string TFS_GetProject();     
}
```

and my return methods is

```
public string TFS_GetProject()
{
    String json = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ProjectId, ProjectName, ProjectDescription ,ClientName ,Duration, "
            + " Manpower, ProjectStatus FROM TFS_mstrProject WHERE pStatus = 'Y'", con);
        con.Open();
        da.Fill(dtbl);
        con.Close();
        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtbl);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        json = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    return json;
}
```

and my Response is like

```
"[
    {
        \"ProjectId\":1.0,
        \"ProjectName\":\"Prematix Messanger - Android\",
        \"ProjectDescription\":\"Basically it  will be using for the internal communication of the office. this application mainly involves  message conversation and attaching doc for both sender and receiver.\",
        \"ClientName\":\"Prematix\",
        \"Duration\":15.0,
        \"Manpower\":4.0,
        \"ProjectStatus\":\"Locked\"
    }
]"
```

I think this is not JSON format. How can I convert this into JSON?

Comment: Why do you think that this is not JSON?

Comment: You used `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtbl)` on it. It‘s pretty normal that it looks like this. It is JSON.

Comment: As far as I know there are Frameworks like 'Jackson' available, to entirely handle JSON back and forth. Keep in Mind that in JAVA a JSON isn‘t represented by an Object as you know it from JavaScript! You have to transform it into a valid JAVA-Class-Structure. Use Jackson for this.